# Is there any way to set static and dynamic route to the same place?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am pretty new to Vue.js and I am creating a webapp with some articles. Is there any way to set static (domain.com/login) and dynamic (domain.com/:category) path to route?

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/:category",
      component: () => import("./views/CategoryView.vue")
    },
    {
      path: "/:category/:article",
      component: () => import("./views/ArticleView.vue")
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: () => import(".views/Login.vue")
    }
  ]
});
```

I am getting the list of categories from database so I can't hard-code paths for every category and I want them to be right after the domain without fake paths as domain.com/category/:category.

Comment: Order matters; just move the /login route to the top of our routes array.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.